# Deep Learning - Keep getting low accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm new to Python (although not to programming - I'm usually programming in JavaScript) and I'm very interested in AI development.
Recently I've been trying to develop a deep learning algorithm by following [this article](https://gogul.dev/software/first-neural-network-keras).

My goal is to predict a set of 7 numbers, based on a CSV file that contains a large list, with each row having 7 numbers as well. The order of the list matters.

I ended up having the following code:

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from numpy import loadtxt, random

random.seed(seed)

dataset = loadtxt("data/Lotto.csv", delimiter=",", skiprows=1)

X = dataset[:, 0:7]

Y = dataset[:, 6]

(X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test) = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=4)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=7, kernel_initializer="uniform", activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer="uniform", activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer="uniform", activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs=100, batch_size=5, shuffle=False)

scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)

print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" %(scores[1] * 100))
```

After running it in Google Colaboratory, while I'm not getting any errors - I noticed that for each epoch, the loss result doesn't change, and as a result, I keep getting low accuracy (~6%).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the possibilities can be endless, starting with how many data points you have, and whether there even is a pattern to begin with. There is no silver bullet here. As a suggestion, try with a simpler model first, don't jump to neural nets. You need to develop a LOT of background first and then try different things out. Whether you realise it or not, you're asking a question that is frankly very broad and tough to answer on here.

Comment: To keep things simple, if you're learning, don't use your own datasets right now (which i assume you are doing). Start with some sample dataset so that the "issues with data" can be eliminated while you learn the ropes.

Comment: Alright. I'll try to learn from a tutorial that is following a certain dataset. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: How many handwritten numbers do you have?

Comment: I downloaded a CSV file from a certain website. I want to analyze it & predict what'll be next using a deep learning model.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing optimizer to `RMSprop` with learning rate of around 0.0001.
RMSprop is usually better than most optimizers and gives better accuracy and lesser loss than others. You could alternatively try SGD, which is also a good optimizer.
Also increase number of parameters, as more trainable parameters leads to the model being trained with more precision and gives a much accurate prediction.
You could update the code to tensorflow 2.x and change the code to :

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from numpy import loadtxt, random

#Rest of the code
....... 
.......
.......

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_shape=(7,), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(64, kernel_initializer="uniform", activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer="uniform", activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001), metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs=100, batch_size=5, shuffle=False)
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" %(scores[1] * 100))
```

Comment: I don't actually know what should be in the `#Rest of the code` thing. In my post, I simply followed a tutorial, without much knowing of what I'm doing. I am curious about the topic of AIs, but I never coded one prior to the post - up until this point, it was only theoretical. What should be in the `#Rest of the code`? Should I keep my code as-is?

Comment: The "rest of the code" part is the random.sees till train_test_split part in your code above, nothing different.

Comment: Try coding it this way, the overall accuracy of your code might increase by almost 10-15%

Comment: The thing is, I'm not quite sure what needs to be on my Y axis. The X axis should contain the number sets, right? But what should the Y axis contain?

Comment: Usually, x is all the numeric columns and y is the result

Comment: You can omit columns like serial number, dates, names, etc. if any present

Comment: Just follow the tutorial there, try making changes only to the parts I've written.

Comment: If the Y axis is representing the result - is it possible to make the Y axis to be the next set of numbers that I expect to get?

Comment: I think what the tutorial is trying to teach is how to predict the winner of the lottery. So y will be the next set of numbers drawn in the lottery, which is actually the result of the lottery.

Comment: Also, change the filter size of your last dense layer to 7, because the output/prediction is an array of 7 numbers.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use this dataset : https://data.ny.gov/Government-Finance/Lottery-Take-5-Winning-Numbers/dg63-4siq

Comment: There are three columns, take y as the winning numbers column and generate a set of random integers for x

Comment: Thanks but I don't need the dataset you linked me to, as my dataset was downloaded from the lottery website of my country

Comment: So if I understand you right, I need the first & last layers to have 7 nodes. As of the Y axis - do I need to modify the CSV in such a way that, for each entry, the first 7 numbers will be the current input and the last 7 numbers will be the to-be-predicted set?

Comment: Could you send the link to the dataset? I will have a better understanding if I saw the dataset.

Comment: I just revisited it just to be sure. There is no error. It's just the language you're unfamiliar with

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but by the looks of it your input is a list of 7 numbers, and you want to output the 7th number in that list. Now by using a sigmoid activation in your last layer, you're restricting your model output to the interval (0,1). Are you sure that your data is in this interval?

Also, your model is way to complicated for that task. You really need only one dense layer without an activation or bias to be able to do this.

Comment: My goal is to be able to predict a set of 7 numbers, based on a large list, in which each entry is a set of 7 numbers. Each time the input should be the next 7 numbers. I don't know how to achieve this. My code above is taken from the linked article-tutorial.

Comment: That's not what you're doing here. But so if I understand correctly you want to predict, based on X[i] what X[i+1] will be? What kind of data do you have, because from your code it looks like you're using Lotto data which might not have the kind of correlations you're looking for. On top of that note that train_test_split shuffles by default.

Comment: Correct, I'm using [lottery data](https://www.pais.co.il/lotto/archive.aspx)

Comment: Like I said, this is my first time attempting to understand how to code an AI. Up to this point, everything was only theoretical - so it's a deep dive for me

Comment: Well unless the lottery uses a really dumb way of drawing its numbers, you can't really expect to get better results than randomness from your model. In the code you posted however, the reason you got low accuracy was probably the sigmoid (but then you're not training to predict X[i+1] from X[i] but instead to predict X[i, 6] from X[i,0:7]). Don't worry about it though, you'll get there. There are a ton of good tutorials out there that will help you.

Comment: What can you suggest me to do to improve my code & my understanding of AI in general?

Comment: Google has a nice tutorial on the basic concepts of machine learning. It might be a good place to start https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/ml-intro